# Creating divs with a div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am generating divs within a div. My script is currently only doing it with in the body. How would make so it the divs are being generated in a div. Many thanks

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var classes = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5'],
  counter = 0;

  makeDiv();


  function makeDiv() {
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    var divsize = 5;
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();
    $newdiv = $("<div class='" + classes[counter] + "'></div>").css({
      'left': posx + 'px',
      'top': posy + 'px'
    });
    $newdiv.appendTo('body').delay(20).fadeIn(100, function () {
      //$(this).remove();
      makeDiv();
    });

    counter = counter < divsize -1 ? counter + 1 : 63;
  }
})
```

Comment: Each new `<div>` you create wants to be inside the previous created `<div>`? In other words, the first **div** have to be inside **body** tag, and then the next one inside the previous **div** and so on?

Comment: can you specify whether or not you want all the divs to be cascading, or if you just want to place them all within a single div on the body of the page?

Comment: @D.Smania Each new div is within the parent div. So the the parent div is in the body tag and the new generated div is within the parent div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then, if you want all created `<div>` by inside one common div called **parent_div**, try next example:

```
var counter = 0;
var classes = ['box1', 'box2', 'box3', 'box4', 'box5'];

$(document).ready(function ()
{
    // Create the parent div of all divs that will be generated.
    // Add this div to the body.

    $('<div id"parent_div"></div>').appendTo('body');

    // Start recursive creation of more divs.

    makeDiv();
});

function makeDiv()
{
    var numRand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 501);
    var divsize = 5;
    var posx = (Math.random() * ($('body').width() - divsize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * ($('body').height() - divsize)).toFixed();

    var newdiv = $('<div class="' + classes[counter] + '"></div>').css({
        'left': posx + 'px',
        'top': posy + 'px',
        'display': 'none' // Since you want they to fadeIn.
    });

    // FIX: can't set counter to 63 because will cause indexing error on array classes.
    //counter = counter < divsize -1 ? counter + 1 : 63;
    counter = counter < (divsize - 1) ? counter + 1 : 0;

    newdiv.appendTo($("#parent_div")).delay(20).fadeIn(100, function ()
    {
        makeDiv();
    });
}
```